# Error: Invalid Chai property: toBe. Did you mean "to"?

Tags: javascript, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I am trying to check that an element is present in an angular website. I am using protractor 5.4.0.

In the header of the my_steps.js file I have this:

```
global.expect = require('chai').expect
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

The code that I am using to assert that the dropdown is present is:

```
Then(/^(.*) is present$/, function (dropdown,callback) {
        expect(element(by.id(dropdown)).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        callback();
```

And the output of the protractor protractor.conf.js command is:

```
When application opened # ../Features/step_definitions/my_steps.js:62
   ✖ Then templateSelection is present # ../Features/step_definitions/my_steps.js:70
       Error: Invalid Chai property: toBe. Did you mean "to"?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the 'chai-as-promised' plug-in that extends Chai with a fluent language for asserting facts about promises. You do have to adjust the assertions slightly. The below page gives good examples.
[Chai as promised page with explanations](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/)

For your issue you will need to change:

`.isPresent()).toBe(true);`

to:

`.isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true);`

Therefore your assertion should look like this:

`expect(element(by.id(dropdown)).isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true);`

**Also note I have not seen the use of `.equals` only `.equal`**

Answer (score 0):

`isPresent()` returns a promise

`expect(element(by.id(dropdown)).isPresent()).to.eventually.equals(true);`